# FFmpeg audio formats: ipod vs mov (for ALAC)

Tags: ffmpeg, codec

In converting to [Apple Lossless (ALAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Lossless_Audio_Codec) using FFmpeg, I have two options:

```bash
ffmpeg -y -i whatever.wav -b:a 256k -ar 16000 -ac 1 -f ipod -acodec:a alac whatever.ipod.m4a
# Output #0, ipod, to 'content/tests/comparing-codecs/whatever.ipod.m4a':

ffmpeg -y -i whatever.wav -b:a 256k -ar 16000 -ac 1 -f mov -acodec:a alac whatever.mov.m4a
# Output #0, mov, to 'content/tests/comparing-codecs/whatever.mov.m4a':
```

*(I could also leave the `-f` alone, which the defaults to ipod.)*

This results in near identical files, from ffprobe:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'content/tests/comparing-codecs/whatever.ipod.m4a':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4A
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:01.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 67 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: alac (alac / 0x63616C61), 16000 Hz, mono, s16p, 63 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'content/tests/comparing-codecs/whatever.mov.m4a':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:01.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 67 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: alac (alac / 0x63616C61), 16000 Hz, mono, s16p, 63 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Only the file size is slightly different, with the ipod file 43 bytes smaller.

I'm able to play both files in on macOS and iPhone, at least on the devices I had access to.

My question is: is there any practical difference between formats? Is a given format preferable for a specific use?

Answer (score 0):

The .m4a will, in theory, be more compatible with web players, and .mov may be more acceptable in older NLEs. I would default to .m4a.

Comment: It would've been better to know the reason behind this -1, I really wondered. It will be 0 (zero) now.